# Yii2 Send parameters from button to modal-ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii2, modal-dialog

i need to put one parameter from button to widget

**data-video="fbnSR-KBOiE"**

to **'param' => 42** like this **'param' => fbnSR-KBOiE**

How can i do this?

```
echo ModalAjax::widget([
'id' => 'showVideo',
'header' => 'Create Company',
//'toggleButton' => [
// 'label' => 'New Company',
// 'class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right'
//],
'url' => \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['youtube/index', **'param' => 42**]), // Ajax view with form to load
'ajaxSubmit' => true, // Submit the contained form as ajax, true by default
// ... any other yii2 bootstrap modal option you need
]);

?>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showVideo" **data-video="fbnSR-KBOiE"** data-backdrop="false">
show video
```

Comment: You can try to use `javascript`, and use events `on show.bs.modal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is sending parameters from button **data-url="watch?v=ik7ysDGWbcw"** to modal through controller **youtube/index** by ajax

```
<span id="play-button" class="fa fa-play-circle play-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#youtubeModal" data-url="watch?v=ik7ysDGWbcw" data-backdrop="false">
</span>


<div class="modal fade" id="youtubeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#youtubeModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        let button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        let youtubeUrl = button.data('url') // Extract info from data-* attributes

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['youtube/index'])?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: {youtubeUrl: youtubeUrl},
            success(response) {
                // Add response in Modal body
                $('.modal-body').html(response);
                //$('#exampleModal').html(response);
                // Display Modal
                //$('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```